# how to reset my root password in mysql docker image

Tags: mysql, docker

I am using MySQL image with docker, so when I want to get inside the MySQL by this command

```
docker exec -it mysql_1 MySQL -u root -p"
```

I have got an error below

```
"ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

and it seems to me that I have forgotten the password

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: If you `docker inspect mysql_1`, is there a `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` environment variable?

Comment: Yes thank you brother it works I have got the password thank you very much

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First access your mysql container with this command

```
docker exec -it mysql_1 bash
```

or

```
docker exec -it mysql bash
```

then follow those steps to reset your root password for your mysql

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-reset-mysql-root-password-on-your-linux-server

Comment: page not found.